# Why does my DLL load properly when given an absolute path but not a relative path?

Tags: c++, dll, cmake

I have created a simple `dll` using `/MDd` flag on `windows 10` using `msvc 2019` compilers. The `dll` only contains a simple add function (like in all the tutorials). After building this library I've copied it into a test folder for explicit linking. Basically, the test passes if I give it the full absolute path to the `dll` but it doesn't load if I only provide the name of the `dll`.

Here is the test code:

```
//test_add.cpp

#include <windows.h>
#include "gtest/gtest.h"

TEST(test, test_add_windows) {
#if defined(_WIN32) || defined (_WIN64)
    typedef int (*addPtr)(int, int);
    // full path works and the test passes
    HINSTANCE hinstLib = LoadLibrary(TEXT("D:\\ACrossPlatformCppLibrary\\test\\ACrossPlatformCppLibrary.dll"));
    // relative path does not work: library fails to load
//    HINSTANCE hinstLib = LoadLibrary(TEXT("ACrossPlatformCppLibrary.dll"));
    std::cout << hinstLib << std::endl;
    ASSERT_NE(hinstLib, nullptr);
    auto add = (addPtr) GetProcAddress(hinstLib, "add");
    ASSERT_NE(add, nullptr);
    int x = 5;
    int y = 6;
    int answer = add(x, y);
    ASSERT_EQ(answer, 11);
    BOOL fFreeResult = FreeLibrary(hinstLib);
#else
    ASSERT_TRUE(true);
#endif
}
```

And my directory tree

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the answer. I ran another test from the same file to get the current directory:

```
TEST(test, test2) {
    char *fileExt;
    char szDir[256]; //dummy buffer
    GetFullPathName(".", 256, szDir, &fileExt);
    printf("Full path: %s\nFilename: %s", szDir, fileExt);
}
```

Which outputs:

```
Full path: D:\ACrossPlatformCppLibrary\cmake-build-debug\test
```

The problem was that I copied the `dll` into the source directory, not the build directory.

Comment: FYI, there is a [`GetCurrentDirectory()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-getcurrentdirectory) function.